# How can we convert a given datetime format in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.6, format-conversion

I have a date time column which is of the following format:

> 2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000

I want my format to be as follows:

> 2019-11-10 07:10:55.865000

How can I do this in PostgreSQL 9.6.11?

Comment: `timestamp` columns don't have "a format". Any format you see, is applied by the SQL client you are using to _display_ the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try making a full roundtrip from text to timestamp, then back to text again:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.US'),
        'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US') AS ts_out;
```

This outputs:

```
2019-11-10 07:10:00.865000
```

### Demo

As a side note, you should seriously consider *not* storing your timestamps as text in the first place.  Ideally, if you want to view your timestamp column a certain way, e.g. for reporting purposes, you should only have to make a single call to `TO_CHAR` with the format mask you want to use.

Comment: My output should be 2019-11-10 07:10:55.865000 instead of 2019-11-10 07:10:00.865000. 55 is missing according to this.

Comment: @amith17 The demo code had a typo in it, the code in the answer was already correct.

Comment: If I convert it from text format to timestamp by using **SELECT
     CAST(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.US'),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.US') AS TIMESTAMP);** the **last three digits of 865000 are lost** and I'm getting **2019-11-10 07:10:55.865** as output. Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `to_char(timestamp, text)` function, e.g. `to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI:SS')`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html